# Android Firebase - setPersistenceEnabled(true) crashing the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I was just trying out Firebase to update Toolbar label of activities from realtime database. I am getting the following error:

```
12-21 00:25:19.890 10295-10295/com.xlr8labs.FirebaseAuth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.xlr8labs.FirebaseAuth, PID: 10295
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xlr8labs.FirebaseAuth/com.xlr8labs.FirebaseAuth.RegisterActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2341)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zzhM(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.xlr8labs.FirebaseAuth.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:35)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Even though I'm using setPersistenceEnabled() before calling any other methods on my database instance, I'm still getting this error. Here is my Activity.java code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        // ------------------ Update activity label from database in realtime ------
        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseInstance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        mFirebaseInstance.getReference("RegisterLabel").keepSynced(true);
        mFirebaseInstance.getReference("RegisterLabel").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Register label changed");
                String appTitle = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(appTitle);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is causing the crash. I'm using the exact same snippet on two other activities...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part `mFirebaseInstance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);` should be just in first Activity. It's shouldn't be called more than once.

Better solution would be to put that line in onCreate method of your Application class. You can read more about it [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but now I'm still getting NullPointer exception at this line:
`mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

Comment: Can you paste stack-trace? That should't be happening.

Comment: After cleaning and rebuilding project. I got it to work. Thanks! :)

Comment: Even better would be to put it in a ContentProvider, of which there is guaranteed to be only one for an application (even when the application ends up spawning multiple processes). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `mFirebaseInstance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);` from your `RegisterActivity` class.

Make a custom class which should extend Application and write it there.

Example :

```
public class JustExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty())
        {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please show me how we can call database instance using this class?

Comment: How can I use this in my RegisterActivity?

Comment: No you don't need to use this in your RegisterActivity. Instead you can create a new java file

Comment: You mean just create the new java file and no changes to RegisterActivity?

Comment: ya and don't forget to remove that line from RegisterActivity

Comment: Even better would be to put it in a ContentProvider, of which there is guaranteed to be only one for an application (even when the application ends up spawning multiple processes). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry to disagree, but ```Application``` is guaranteed to be only one; It's a Singleton.

Comment: That's what I thought too, until we discovered that `Application` is *once per process*. So for multi-process apps, there may be multiple instances. Content providers on the other hand are guaranteed to be run only once, even for multi-process apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag = true; //before onCreate() method

//inside onStart() Method
if(flag)
{ 
  firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what you code actually does and why it solves the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Model class and use Method inside it such as the one mentioned below.

```
public class DatabaseUtility {

    private static FirebaseDatabase database;

    public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase(){
        if(database==null){
            database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
        return database;
    }
}
```

This will return database instance and you can use `database.getReference();` method to get Root reference. This will also save some time if the database object is already present.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply uninstall the previously installed app. And let it install the fresh app. It will resolve the problem.