# Kotlin Fix setPersistenceEnabled(true)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

How can I fix the following Error inside my activity?

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.

I set setPersistenceEnabled() like that in my activity:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.ViewThat_add -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, Add::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        R.id.ViewThat_delete -> {
            delete()
        }
        R.id.ViewThat_Download -> {
            enablePersistence()
            download()


        }


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}

private fun enablePersistence() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
}
```

Inside the documentation it was made very similar to this, I don't really know how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you need to enable persistence before making any other calls to the database. A common way to do this is to put the call into the `onCreate` of your main activity, or in a subclass of `Application`, or a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: class ViewPlaylist : AppCompatActivity() {

    private fun enablePersistence() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enablePersistence()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_playlist)
        setPlaylistInfo()


    }                                                                                                                                                    I have made like that but the activity still crashes.

Comment: Interesting. It means that there must be some other call to the database before you enable persistence. Have a look at some of the other questions about the same error message, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753991/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-calls-to-setpersistenceenabled), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448186/setpersistenceenabledtrue-crashes-app) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250507/android-firebase-setpersistenceenabledtrue-crashing-the-app).

Comment: I fixed the problem I think but can I some how check that the data has been stored?

Comment: Run the app, disable the network, run the app again?

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot the whole purpose of that :D. Thank you again!

Comment: This question comes really late but I have done some testing and I noticed that when I switch between fragments the enablePersistence() don't work even when I put as first in onCreate, any idea how to fix that? Because the problem remains even when I write the enablePersistence() call at first in the fun that call the fragment in the Main Activity. Also the app crashes when I return from a non Firebase fragment to a Firebase fragment were enablePersistence() is included, I don't really need it its just something I noticed...

Comment: I have no idea why it would't work when using fragments, but would recommend using an `Application` subclass or `ContentProviders`. But if you have a (new) problem with persistence in those situations, I'd recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create a new question with that.

Comment: I have found the answer to that , you have to write the enablePersistence() call inside the Activity where the fragments transactions are handled. I will create a new post and share this solution just in case somebody has that same problem